# SQL: Searching at least 2 similar rows between different tables

Tags: sql, search

This is my current setup:
I have 2 tables, **RECIPE** and **INGREDIENTS**.
**RECIPE** holds the *ID* among other data. **INGREDIENTS** has X rows needed for each RECIPE.
How can one match 2 recipes with at least 2 matching ingredients?
I can do it specifying which ingredient must match, but my problem is when the recipe has more than 10 ingredients and I need two recipes that uses the same 2 ingredients, not knowing which ones.
Sorry my English, is not my natural language. I'll post more details if needed, or if I wasn't clear enough.

Pratical example:
Recipe 1 has: fish, potatoes and salt.
Recipe 2 has: turkey and rice.
Recipe 3 has: fish, rice and salt.
Recipe 4 has: turkey, potatoes and salt.

Result based on recipe 1 should be: 4
Result based on recipe 2 should be: None
Result based on recipe 3 should be: 1
Result based on recipe 4 should be: 1
(Yep, I need to run every recipe based on a filter not explained here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
WITH REC_ING AS (
SELECT *
FROM RECIPE AS T1
INNER JOIN
INGREDIENTS AS T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID)

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT T1.ID AS ID1, T2.ID AS ID2
FROM REC_ING AS T1
INNER JOIN
REC_ING AS T2
ON T1.INGREDIENT_ID = T2.INGREDIENT_ID 
AND T1.ID != T2.ID) AS JOINED_TAB
GROUP BY ID1, ID2
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

This is a rough copy. If it sounds like what you're looking for, I can make a more elaborate example (incl. SQL Fiddle).

Comment: Hmmmm... not working, still trying to figure out. Recipes and Ingredients was just an example. The real table has nothing to do with food :D :D :D

Comment: Well. I'll stick to this one. it's more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to extend this to more than 2 ingredients, or for a more detailed explanation of the problem space and what alternative queries exist, look at this extended article about **[RELATIONAL DIVISION](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)**.

---

```
select DISTINCT A.recipe_id, C.recipe_id other_recipe_id
from INGREDIENTS A
join INGREDIENTS B on A.recipe_id = B.recipe_id and A.ingredient < B.ingredient
join INGREDIENTS C on A.recipe_id < C.recipe_id and C.ingredient = A.ingredient
join INGREDIENTS D on C.recipe_id = D.recipe_id and D.ingredient < B.ingredient
```

A and B are two different ingredients belonging to the same recipe.
Using these, we join to C and D, being the same two ingredients (A=C,B=D) but where C and D belong to the same other recipe.

This will return the distinct IDs of EVERY PAIR of recipes that share 2 ingredients. You can get the actual recipe names by joining back to the recipe table twice for the names.

Comment: That's nice, but if I need 3 matching ingredients I had to change the code. But I'll run a few tests on it. Thanks

Comment: with few modifications this works nice (keep in mind that original table has nothing to do with food)

Comment: Richard, I'm having troubles getting one value that is on RECIPE, can u help?

Comment: I have no idea what you are after, perhaps you can ask a new question with DDL (table structures), sample data, what you expect, what you have tried, and what is not working as expected? As much as I can tell, the query works correctly for the sample data in the question, so `having trouble getting one value` is quite hard to interpret.

Comment: Sorry. Still running some tests here. I'll add the info when I can.